# How do I normalize and denormalize data in R?

Tags: r, normalization, denormalization

I have data that contains 14 columns of predictors and 1 column of solution variable(y).

I wanted to know if there are any inbuilt functions to normalize and denormalize data in R.

Thank you.

Comment: can you explain a bit more for a broader audience?  and give a reproducible example?  You *might* be looking for the `reshape` function, or Hadley Wickham's widely used `reshape2` and/or `tidyr` packages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

normDataWithin of package {Rmisc} can be used:  http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/Rmisc/docs/normDataWithin

Else following methods can be used:

(variable-mean)/sd  . Following code can be used for a data.frame:

```
mydata$myNormalizedVar<-(mydata$myvar-mean(mydata$myvar))/sd(myvar)
```

log (log10), log2, and square root (sqrt)

Normal quantile normalization or normal quantile transformation. Try:

```
quantNorm = function(x){qnorm(rank(x,ties.method = "average")/(length(x)+1))}
hist(quantNorm(1:10000),100)
```